# Greeks' gas lamps

Tags: history, gentiles, chanuka, heterodox, lighting

I once heard that there is a source that says the Greeks invented gas lamps or some sort of street lights which enabled the Jews to roam the streets at night and not be with their families. The plan was, if people aren't home people can intermingle with each other. Does anyone know of a Jewish source for this?

Comment: What's it got to do with Chanukah? (I mean, I can guess, but can you tie it in more explicitly?)

Comment: gas lamps in the second century bc?

Comment: @DoubleAA Apparently, they used [oil lamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_light#History).